# php artisan migrate [PDOException] could not find driver

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, laravel-5

When I write command "php artisan migrate" from mysql connection,linux terminal gives this error :`[PDOException] could not find driver`.

When I add to 
php.ini

```
extension=pdo.so 
extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

, 
error has changing like this:

```
PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20121212/pdo_mysql.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20121212/pdo_mysql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0 PHP Warning: Module 'PDO' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

[PDOException]
could not find driver
```

How can we solve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: can you check that ___php_pdo_mysql.dll___ exist or not?

Comment: I am working with Linux Mint

Comment: `locate pdo_mysql.so`

Comment: @badman btw i would suggest you to use either centos or ububtu as server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi you need to install php pdo driver 
 Open terminal

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
```

Restart Apache server

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```